# Why does a "never-repeating" nonce limit a key to safely encrypt only a single block?

Tags: randomness, nonce, siv

This questions comes from a section outlined in [RFC 5297 on SIV-AES](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297#section-1.3.2). The paragraph in particular outlines the idea of a never repeating nonce vs an "almost always" non-repeating nonce.

> If the nonce is random, a requirement that it never repeat will limit the amount of data that can be safely protected with a single key to one block. More sensibly, a random nonce is required to "almost always" be non-repeating, but that will drastically limit the amount of data that can be safely protected.

I don't understand the limitation described in the first sentence. Given an IV and a nonce, what exactly about "never repeating" prevents encrypting more than a single block per key?

It seems to imply that I would need to generate BOTH a new key and nonce for each block I want to encrypt. My current reading of this would imply that I would need to generate a new key AND nonce for each block in say CTR mode but I know this isn't true.

Comment: I think the idea here is that a strong "never repeat" won't allow you to take the chance of $2^{-256}$ that the first two blocks will have the same random nonces.

Comment: I was about to agree with @SEJPM... but nonces are per-message, not per-block, no? 

Comment: @LuisCasillas That's my problem indeed. It can't refer to the underlying cipher by itself as there's no nonce in a single block application, only a key. The section specifically says "a single key to one block" regarding the nonce. I can't make heads or tails of it.